# Personal e-mail address on Heroku

Tags: email, heroku

Right now, my Rails website is being hosted on a regular virtual host, running CentOS and cPanel, the classical way. I also have an e-mail address on my domain, and my host also, obviously, provides an e-mail server.

I would like to move my portfolio website to a PaaS provider, such as Heroku. However, I am unsure whether I will still be able to receive e-mails on e-mail addresses associated with my domain name, when my site is hosted on Heroku.

If not, what could be an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with that.

If you have a dedicated mail-server, You just have to solve it with DNS configuration. A lot of domain sellers give you free DNS manager as well, if they don't there're bunch of other services that can host your DNS stuff(where they might ask you to transfer your domain).

Also be aware that [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) doesn't provide any mail server for you.

You have two options:

- Keep you current regular hosting account just for its mail feature.
- Use [Gmail Google app](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/products.html#gmail) which is a lot cheaper!

Comment: But Heroku doesn't seem to provide an actual mail server I could point to...

Comment: @AndreiBârsan I've updated the answer.

Comment: I see, so there's no way to just host it all in one place, like on VPS hosting. Well, I guess I'll use the first option, thank you!